# Hibernate : Class is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate throws a strange error

> Hibernate: select user0_.userID as userID0_, user0_.password as
>   password0_ from user user0_ where user0_.userID='admin' and
>   user0_.password='admin' org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   action is not mapped [from action where id = 'MADEX240214']   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)

is there anything wrong with my code ?

```
public String insertActions(ArrayList<Action> data , String[] check)
    {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = null;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) 
        {
            if(check[i].compareTo("Update")==0)
            {
                query = session.createQuery("update Action set Last = :Last ,"
                        + " Adjusted_Last =:Adjusted_Last where idAction = :idAction");

                query.setDouble("Last", data.get(i).getLast());
                query.setDouble("Adjusted_Last", data.get(i).getAdjustLast());
                query.setParameter("idAction", data.get(i).getIdAction());
                int result = query.executeUpdate();
            }
            else
            {
                session.save(data.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        return "ERROR";
    }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

Comment: post your hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 1):

starting from Hibernate 5.1 we have to write HibernateUtil in such manner

public class HibernateUtil {

```
private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY;

static{
    try {
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        SESSION_FACTORY = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}
public static Session openSession() {
    return SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What's the full stack trace? It doesn't appear to come from that section of code. The error is on a select from 'action', not update.

I notice in your update statement, you reference the table as 'Action'. HQL queries are case sensitive. Check your mappings. 'action' != 'Action'